# How can I apply Residue in a functional-style way?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, functional-style

Let me suppose that I have got some expression, for example

```
f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)
```

and also a list of a form:

```
{1,2}
```

How can I apply `Residue` in the way that the final form will be:

```
{Residue[f_{1}[x],{x,1}]+Residue[f_{2}[x],{x,1}],Residue[f_{1}[x],{x,2}]+Residue[f_{2}[x],{x,2}]}
```

I am interested only in the functional-like style solution, not procedural ones.

Comment: You will need to get the syntax correct. (1) Variables cannot use underscores. Also, if you have in mind subscripts you can use them directly but LaTeX notation will not be changed automagically. (2) Curly braces denote arrays (List in WL) and cannot be used as parentheses. After correcting for that you can look into using `Map` or `Table` to get the result you seek.

Comment: With `expr = f[1][x] + f[2][x];
list = {1, 2, 3};`, you can do `Table[Residue[expr, {x, k}], {k, list}]` or `Residue[expr, {x, #}] & /@ list`, for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first off, I refer you to Daniel Lichtblau's comment. But, for pedagogical purposes, I'll try to explain a functional (perhaps overly so) approach.

Let's start with your first expression. I would remove the `x` argument from the expression. The reason is that in your desired result, you have a repeat of that same argument, which means you have coupling between two different expressions. If for some reason, you want `y` to be your formal argument, you'd be stuck (or at least the solution wouldn't be very general, so you'd have to tweak it every time). Also, I'm not sure what your `f1`, `f2` are, and we might need to worry about things evaluating before you want them to. So, we'll start with this:

```
expression = f1 + f2
```

(I'll let you deal with the syntax however you want, but the simplest thing for this exercise it to just tack the index onto the function name.)

Next we'll specify the "centers" (I don't know if that's the right jargon) for your residues:

```
centers = {1, 2}
```

Now we need to figure out how to combine these together and apply the `Residue` appropriately. There are several functions that combine expressions together in various "pairwise" ways: `Through`, `Thread`, `MapThread`, `Inner`, `Outer`. I didn't give a whole lot of thought to what was optimal, but `Outer` seemed reasonable. So, defering how we specify the exact sub-expression, we get the general form like this:

```
Outer[tbd, {expression}, centers]
(* {{tbd[f1+f2,1],tbd[f1+f2,2]}} *)
```

This is a bit awkward, because we introduced an unnecessary level, but this might actually be a benefit, because it means you can do this transformation on several expressions simultaneously. That extra level also appears in our output, so if you really don't want that extra level, you can just flatten the result.

Okay, so what should `tbd` be? Well, we want a function that takes two arguments and produces

```
Residue[f1[x], {x, 1}] + Residue[f2[x], {x, 1}]
```

where the first argument was `f1+f2` and the second was `1`. So, it looks like we're mapping something over the first argument:

```
tbd = Map[tbd2, #1] &
```

Now for `tbd2`. We want something like this:

```
tbd2 = Residue[#[x], {x, <second argument to tbd>}] &
```

I think the clearest way to do this is to switch to the explicit `Function` syntax:

```
tbd2 = Function[{fn}, Residue[fn[x], {x, #2}]]
```

Putting it together without the intermediate `tbd`/`tbd2` definitions:

```
Outer[Map[Function[{fn}, Residue[fn[x], {x, #2}]], #1] &, {expression}, centers]

(* {{Residue[f1[x],{x,1}]+Residue[f2[x],{x,1}],Residue[f1[x],{x,2}]+Residue[f2[x],{x,2}]}} *)
(* Without definitions for `f1`,`f2`, this will evaluate to {{0,0}} *)
```

It's not necessary to do this as a one-liner. You could keep the intermediate definitions (but with better names that `tbd`). You can also bundle up this whole operation into its own function. And you can find alternatives to `Outer` that you like better.

Also, given the `Table` suggestions in the comments, I should clarify why I offered the above solution. I think `Table` would be a perfectly acceptable solution, but it isn't really functional, in my opinion. You said you didn't want `For` or `While`, and `Table` is effectively the same sort of loop semantic. Any time you need to introduce a temporary, semantically arbitrary variable to manage state, you are in a procedural world.

Comment: I agree `table` is not exactly functional programming. But it can be a natural thing to use. Granted, it's not required here. (Thanks for elaborating; I upvoted of course).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I totally agree. Certainly no reason to avoid Table or anything. I just interpreted the question in a particular way (which was maybe too strict).